# What is the meaning of "put white out on sth"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have read an article which includes the phrase "`put white out on sth`", but I am unable to guess its meaning.

Despite referring to http://dictionary.cambridge.org/, I haven't been able to look up this term. Can anyone  explain it?

Comment: See meaning #3 here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/white+out

Comment: The reason you could not find it at the cambridge.org website is that the article you were reading evidently misspelled the name of the product. The name is actually spelled Wite-Out; if you input that into the cambridge.org search box, you will find it. The product itself is an opaque white correction fluid which competes with similar brands, such as *Liquid Paper, Snopake* and *Tipp-Ex*. (For more information, see the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_fluid).) I once had a colleague who liked to refer to it as 'mistake juice'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"White out" (or more correctly, *Wite-out*) is [correction liquid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wite-Out) that is used for correcting mistakes written, printed or drawn in ink.

She ***put white out on*** her mistakes but didn't write her corrections.

He used ***white out*** to cover up the drips of ink on his drawing.